# DIV to scroll horizontally instead of vertical - Pure CSS Approach

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have already seen a lot of answers about this. The given solutions were:

- `white-space: nowrap;`
- `display: inline-block;`

But my case is different. This is the exact output of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

I am not sure if there's something that I can do to fill in like this, something like a top-down to bottom-right way. I am planning for a pure CSS solution, but I couldn't get. I was able to get only the traditional left-right to bottom-right way! `:(`

My code so far has been like this:

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font-size: 80%;}

ul, ul li {line-height: 1;}
ul li {cursor: pointer; text-align: center; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out; transition: all 0.5s ease-out;}
ul li span {display: none;}
ul li:hover span {display: inline;}


#grid {width: 80%; margin: 15px auto; display: -webkit-flex; display: -moz-flex; display: -ms-flex; display: -o-flex; display: flex; -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; flex-flow: row wrap;}
#grid li {list-style: none; width: 75px; height: 75px; background-color: #0c9; display: inline-block; margin: 5px; flex: auto; line-height: 75px; font-weight: 600;}
#grid li.selected {background-color: #096;}
#grid li.unavailable {background-color: #633; color: #fff;}
#grid li.unavailable span,
#grid li.selected span {display: inline;}
```

```html
<h3>For just three.</h3>
<ul class="border-outside" id="grid">
    <li id="g1"><span>G1</span></li>
    <li id="g2"><span>G2</span></li>
    <li id="g3"><span>G3</span></li>
</ul>
<h3>For filling a complete row.</h3>
<ul class="border-outside" id="grid">
    <li id="g1"><span>G1</span></li>
    <li id="g2"><span>G2</span></li>
    <li id="g3"><span>G3</span></li>
    <li id="g4"><span>G4</span></li>
    <li id="g5"><span>G5</span></li>
    <li id="g6"><span>G6</span></li>
</ul>
<h3>For More...</h3>
<ul class="border-outside" id="grid">
    <li id="g1"><span>G1</span></li>
    <li id="g2"><span>G2</span></li>
    <li id="g3"><span>G3</span></li>
    <li id="g4"><span>G4</span></li>
    <li id="g5"><span>G5</span></li>
    <li id="g6"><span>G6</span></li>
    <li id="g7"><span>G7</span></li>
    <li id="g8"><span>G8</span></li>
    <li id="g9"><span>G9</span></li>
    <li id="g10"><span>G10</span></li>
    <li id="g11"><span>G11</span></li>
    <li id="g12"><span>G12</span></li>
</ul>
```

It increases height-wise, but not width-wise. Also, I cannot use `white-space: nowrap`, because that doesn't fill height-wise at all! Any help in this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: will your 'columns' only ever house 3 items? or will this be responsive in that your items are of a fixed height and when the browser height is increased you get 4, 5, 6... items top to bottom?

Comment: Good question! Yes, it should increase accordingly to the browser's height.

Comment: have you had a play with css3 columns? http://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/ they are fairly universally supported now: http://caniuse.com/#search=column

Comment: The browser's gonna be one. So, no problem with that. Will this spread horizontally? Or this will be like traditional top down? Lemme check. `:)`

Comment: columns are designed to let you fill top to bottom, then left to right. Without playing with it yet, i believe if you set up the `column-fill` attribute correctly it should also force content out horizontally rather than letting the overflow push down. (I have to admit though, this would be much much easier with JS `;)`)

Comment: @haxxxton Nopes, I am not able to achieve it. So far I have done this: http://jsbin.com/ziligaheco/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: you were missing the browser specific prefixes.. i will create an answer for you as i got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So CSS columns will give you pretty close to the solution you are looking for, however i would change up your `html` a little to make the way they flow on from one another a little nicer. The reason you get the occasional issue where the 'even' columns at right up against the top is to do with the height of the container (`.box`) not being a perfect divisible number of the height of its internal elements.. i would either look at using some js to give yourself a custom scrollbar for these areas (this will stop it becoming part of the layout), or fix the height of the container to a height that doesnt cause this issue (issue can be replicated by changing `.box`'s height from 205px to 200px)

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-inner">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box,
.box li {
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  list-style: none;
}
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  overflow: auto; 
  -webkit-column-width: 35px;
     -moz-column-width: 35px;
          column-width: 35px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
     -moz-column-gap: 0;
          column-gap: 0;
  height: 205px;
}
.box .item {
  display: block; 
  padding: 5px; 
  width: 35px; 
  height: 35px; 
}
.box .item .item-inner{
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/hupozidine/3/edit?html,css,output)**

Comment: Looks promising. Lemme check! `:)`